# Передача переменной в процедуру класса формы PascalABC.net в редакторе форм

Tags: winforms, pascal, pascalabc.net

В классе формы win2 = class(Form) есть процедура, которая должна поменять картинку в окне win3:

```
  procedure whatwaspressed(sender: Object; e: KeyEventArgs);
  begin
   w3.pb1.Image := Image.FromFile('C:\PABCWork.NET\Меню\картинки\2.png'); //должна менять картинку в win3
  end;
```

В разделе implementation, где объявляется и инициализируется переменная w3, отвечающая за окно win3:

```
implementation
var w3 : win3;    //объявление

procedure win2.win2_Load(sender: Object; e: EventArgs);//запускается при загрузке окна 
begin
  w3 := new win3; //инициализация
  w3.Show;        //показ окна
  self.KeyDown += FormKeyDown; 
  self.KeyDown += whatwaspressed;
```

Как сделать так, чтобы w3 была доступна в процедуре whatwaspressed? Как ее передать туда, чтобы были возможны изменения и было возможно обращение к ней из процедуры?

Comment: **Вот проект, который не компилится как раз на этом месте:** **[ссылка](https://yadi.sk/d/Bhu28BYw3GmkhV)**

Answer (score 0):

Сам решил вопрос: нужно было объявить переменную в public разделе класса.